# Intellij uses "mvn grails:exec" instead of original grails command

Tags: grails, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Grails project with `pom.xml` that is treated as Maven project by IntelliJ

When I execute a Grails command using the <kbd>CTRL + ALT + g</kbd> shortcut Intellij directs it to maven.

This works correctly for most Grails commands.

The problem is some commands fails to execute for example - `run-app`

How can I run Grails commands from Intellij IDEA using the Grails console when the project is treated as a maven project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87256). This comment helped me:

> To run Grails application without maven you can comment grails maven plugin in pom.xml or disable maven plugin.

After commenting plugin in pom.xml everything works ok

Answer (score 0):

By default, IntelliJ creates a run-config for your Grails server, so no need for the `run-app` command

For all other commands, you can use `ctrl` + `alt` + `g`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because `run-app` run-config still runs maven `grails:exec`